# Rotating a UIButton by 90 degrees every time the button is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, rotation

How do you rotate a UIButton by 90 degrees each time the button is clicked and also keep track of each rotated position/angle?

Here is the code I have so far but it only rotates once:

```
@IBAction func gameButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.05, animations: ({
        self.gameButtonLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2))
    }))
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
self.gameButtonLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2))
```

Should be changed to

```
// Swift 3 - Rotate the current transform by 90 degrees.
self.gameButtonLabel.transform = self.gameButtonLabel.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(M_PI_2))

// OR

// Swift 2.2+ - Pass the current transform into the method so it will rotate it an extra 90 degrees.
self.gameButtonLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.gameButtonLabel.transform, CGFloat(M_PI_2))
```

With `CGAffineTransformMake...`, you create a brand new transform and overwrite any transform that was already on the button. Since you want to append 90 degrees to the transform that already exists (which could be 0, 90, etc degrees rotated already), you need to add to the current transform. The second line of code I gave will do that.

Comment: The Swift 3 version give an error: Value of type 'CGAffineTransform' has no member 'rotated'

AND 

The Swift 2.2+ version give an error: Extra argument in call

Comment: Hmmm. Which Xcode beta are you on? They keep changing all the method names up on me. I think the code I posted is from Xcode 8 beta 5.

Comment: I haven't upgrade to Xcode 8 beta as yet. I'm currently using Xcode 7.3.1 but I still get Swift 3 auto-correction suggestions from Xcode when I'm writing my code.

Comment: I made a new project, put one button in a view, and hooked up an action to the button. That button's action is this line of code: `sender.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(sender.transform, CGFloat(M_PI_2))`. It does what you are looking for. I cannot get the Extra argument in call error. This code runs on Xcode 7.3.1/Swift 2.2 and Xcode 8 beta 6/Swift 2.3. I also verified that the Swift 3 code I gave works on Xcode 8 beta 6/Swift 3.

Comment: Yesssss lol Thank you so much man. I really appreciated all your efforts and constantly replies. I already upvoted your answer. Let me know if there's anything else I can do for you in return. Thanks

Comment: Oh yea. My bad I forgot about that. Thanks again

Comment: But no animation?

Answer (score 22):

Swift 4:

```
@IBOutlet weak var expandButton: UIButton!

var sectionIsExpanded: Bool = true {
    didSet {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
            if self.sectionIsExpanded {
                self.expandButton.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            } else {
                self.expandButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2.0)
            }
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func expandButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sectionIsExpanded = !sectionIsExpanded
}
```

Comment: The best answer!