# Rotate image every time when press a button - swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to code and I don't know how to rotate my image every time i press on the same button. In my code I can rotate it ones. I already tried a loop and while-infinitive statement but it doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
@IBAction func rotate(_ sender: Any) {


UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0.5, animations:
 ({self.image.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 90.0 * 3.14/180.0)
     )
}
}
```

Comment: But you're not new to searching, right? This question has been answered so many times here...

Comment: I'am sorry but I can't find the answer on my question. Many questions are answered before the new update. And the rotation function has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're messing up the parenthesis and the curly brackets. I believe your code should be something like this:

```
@IBAction func rotate(_ sender: Any) {

     UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0.5, animations: { 
          self.image.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 90.0 * 3.14/180.0) 
     }) 

}
```

Comment: I checked the parenthesis and the curly brackets but it still isn't rotation more than ones.

Comment: take a look at this question [Rotating a UIButton by 90 degrees every time the button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045122/rotating-a-uibutton-by-90-degrees-every-time-the-button-is-clicked)