# Rotate a UIButton with an angle by a new anchorPoint

Tags: swift, xcode, rotation, uibutton

I'm trying to Rotate a button basically with a new anchorPoint. Normally anchor points are right in the center of the views. So I want to change the anchor point to right bottom of the frame of my Button.

I've tried to set an anchor point to the right bottom corner of the button frame and tried to rotate the whole button for 60 degrees to right hand side. It does rotate with the code below. But the rotation seems a bit random to me.

What I wanted was rotating a button with an anchor point(which is right bottom point of the button frame) and rotation angle is meant to be 60 degrees to the right hand side

So here is my basic code.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
   let anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
    LoginScreenSelectionButton.layer.anchorPoint = anchorPoint // setting new anchor
    LoginScreenSelectionButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 0.33)
}
```

My code seems logical and pretty easy to me. What is wrong about it?

I've added an image below. What I'm actually trying to do is drawing the shape below. I've drawn triangle images from adobe photoshop and added those photos to my button in swift.

Now I want to get a full circle from those triangle buttons. To do that, what I thought to do was creating each triangle button from the same point. So they will be on the top of each other.

To create a circular shape I wanted to change the angles of each triangle by adding 60 degree difference between each other(while the anchor point is the right bottom of the button frames).

With that logic I thought that I Would get a perfect circular shape which is created by 6 triangle shaped buttons. So by creating this shape I get 6 different buttons which seems to create a circular shape all together.

Is that approach logical as well?

EDIT: Sorry for long explanation hopefully that will give some information to you about what I'm trying to accomplish

[Triangle Button shapes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT8uK.png)

Thanks

Comment: "but it doesn't work as I wanted" But you have not told us what you _do_ want. Explain what the code does and how that differs from what you desire; please do not just say "doesn't work", that's meaningless.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/39045242/12783209 could help

Comment: BTW, an angle of 0.33 doesn't really make sense. Angles in iOS are expressed in radians, where 2π radians is a full circle. If you want to rotate by 1/3 of a full rotation, that angle would be `CGFloat.pi*2.0/3.0`

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what it does and how it fails to meet your goals.

Comment: So sorry for misexplanation. Tried to explain the question a bit more clear. Hopefully that will be easier to understand

Comment: Done with editing. Tried to explain everything I'm trying to do. Hopefully it will be more clear with my new explanation. Ask away if somethings are not that clear. Thank you so much

Comment: I've created a new question about the same thing. But it is more clear now. Will be really glad if you check it there. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66294433/changing-the-anchor-point-of-a-button-and-then-rotating-the-button-by-its-ancho