# Changing the anchor point of a button and then rotating the button by it's anchor

Tags: swift, xcode, rotation, uibutton, anchorpoint

I'm trying to rotate my button by it's anchor point which is meant to be it's frame's right bottom corner. The rotation that I want is 60 degrees to the right.

So basically I want a button which rotates 60 degrees to right by it's new anchor point which is button frame's right bottom instead of it's center.

Outlet name of my button is: **LoginScreenSelectionButton**

So the code that I use is

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: LoginScreenSelectionButton.frame.width, y: LoginScreenSelectionButton.frame.height)
    LoginScreenSelectionButton.layer.anchorPoint = anchorPoint // setting new anchor
    LoginScreenSelectionButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(60 * Double.pi/180))

}
```

When I use this code my button just disappears. I suppose that it rotates with a weird anchor point. Am I setting the anchor points wrong or rotation code is wrong?

I am adding the desired pre-rotation and post-rotation positions as well.

[Initial position angle of the triangle Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0upp.png)

[The exact rotation that I want to have after the rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6l2T.png)

Thank you.